# Undefined value is storing in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, append, undefined

[image]

I am getting a blank row stored in the table by this code

```
<table id="jobSkills" ">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td  class="col-xs-4"> Skill </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><span>addSkills">+ Add Skills</span><p>
```

jQuery Add+++ More script:

```
var skillcount=0;
$(".addSkills").click(function(){
    $('#jobSkills tr:last').after('<tr><td><input name="skill['+skillcount+'][title]" type="text" "></td></tr>');
    skillcount++;
});
```

Controller code to store in db:

```
foreach($_POST["skill"] as $k=>$key)
{
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO r_job_skill (id_job,title) values ('".$jobId."','".$key["title"]."')");
}
```

Comment: Well what is the question?

Comment: @Epodax if you see the image last value is storing as empty it should not come.

Comment: Then write that into your question, the title isn't meant to be your entire question text.

Comment: A GUESS: The user hits the `Add Skill` and your js adds a new blank row. The user does not bother entering anything in the new row. So you have to look for this situation in the PHP script before you insert a blank row

Comment: ANOTHER GUESS: You provide a blank row for the user to enter a skill, you dont look for that blank row in the data passedto the PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Might be two possible cases.

Either you are getting the null values to you php File.
Perform the insert Operation when there are all the values are available at PHP File

```
if($_POST["skill"] !='')
{
 // insert Query goes Here
}
```

Or you are send an Extra value to the PHP File , with out other values
Check you HTML Code , You Might have an Extra Name with the Parameter, that is bringing the values to your PHP File.

Answer (score 1):

change your script code as per bellow

```
var skillcount=0;
$(".addSkills").click(function(){
    $('#jobSkills tr:last').after('<tr><td><input name="skill[]" type="text" "></td></tr>');
    skillcount++;
});
```

also change your php code as per bellow

```
foreach($_POST["skill"] as $value)
{
$conn->query("INSERT INTO r_job_skill (id_job,title) values ('".$jobId."','".$value."')");
}
```